# How to do a web page diagram with clickable locations

Tags: javascript, html, svg, graphics

Never done this before, but I think people used to capture the location of the click, if possible, and map that to a location in a bitmap image. That just seems like a whole pile of trouble to me, especially with a resizing of the image.

Now I suspect a better way is to have an SVG image, with anchor elements embedded, so they adjust their location with a resizing.

Is there, on the very slim chance, any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using svg is the easiest option there. Use svg.js, raphaёl or snap.svg or some other library. I prefer svg.js (plugins available, object oriented, syntax sugar for some methods, lightweight) but basically they are all the same though neither of them is perfect. So here is the code to create a clickable line (save it to .html file and run, don't forget to download svg.js):

```
<div id="svg"></div>
<script src="svg.js"></script>
<script>
onload = function() {
    var draw = SVG('svg') //we are going to draw in a div with id='svg'

    var line = draw.line('30%', 80, 180, 60) //coords can be in %, px or other css units
    line.attr( { 'stroke': '#f00', 'stroke-width': 5 } ) //styled with css
      //there are also shortcut methods like stroke('#f00')
    .on('click', function() { draw.text('click') }) //method calls can be chained
}
</script>
```

Svg elements are part of html and they are styled with css, so it's much easier to manipulate them.

Download svg.js and see examples at https://svgdotjs.github.io/installation/

Read documentation at https://svgdotjs.github.io

Forget about mapping, it's boring unproductive and hard to maintain. There might be other options but I doubt there is something simpler than svg (if you use a library).

Since you were considering usage of mapping to make clickable locations on a diagram I suppose you are not drawing some trivial charts and existing charting libraries (there is plenty either svg based or not) won't serve you. Writing a library that will draw your kind of diagrams using svg library of your choice shouldn't be hard.

To make such a library I just write functions (or wrapper objects) to draw each class of objects (one function per class) that needs visual representation plus a couple of auxillary functions (e.g. for conversions between coordinate systems).

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Now I need something to draw my images, e.g. generate a set of shapes and coordinates to feed to whatever SVG library I end up using.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with the `usemap` attribute of the `img` or `object` tag along with an associated `map` tag containing `area` tags that define arbitrary shapes, each of which can be associated with an `href`.

The following example is from the current [HTML5 spec draft at W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/image-maps.html)

```
<p>
 Please select a shape:
 <img src="shapes.png" usemap="#shapes"
      alt="Four shapes are available: a red hollow box, a green circle, a blue triangle, and a yellow four-pointed star.">
 <map name="shapes">
  <area shape=rect coords="50,50,100,100"> <!-- the hole in the red box -->
  <area shape=rect coords="25,25,125,125" href="red.html" alt="Red box.">
  <area shape=circle coords="200,75,50" href="green.html" alt="Green circle.">
  <area shape=poly coords="325,25,262,125,388,125" href="blue.html" alt="Blue triangle.">
  <area shape=poly coords="450,25,435,60,400,75,435,90,450,125,465,90,500,75,465,60"
        href="yellow.html" alt="Yellow star.">
 </map>
```

Comment: But, as I said in my question, what if I resize the image, then all the co-ords are off, or is there a god and <map> updates them for me?